# Angular - passing data in routing

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rest, routes

I am trying to implement the routing in my app. My goal is simple: after clicking on one of the rows of my table, the app should show the specific details of the selected row (speedway rider in this case).

I'm stuck on the point where the path after click works correctly, but the page returns no data with the following information in the console:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

I have a feeling that I almost there, but after hours of combinations I decided to ask for help. More code below, I would be grateful for any ideas :)

**service.ts**

```
  getRider(id) : Observable<Rider> {
    return this._http
      .get("http://node.gurustats.usermd.net:60519/pgee2020" + `/${id}`)
      .map(result => (this.result = result.json().data));
  }
```

**subpage.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Rider } from "../interfaces/rider";
import { SpeedwayService } from "../../speedway.service";
import { ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: "gs-zawpgee2020",
  templateUrl: "./zawpgee2020.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./zawpgee2020.component.less"]
})
export class ZawPgee2020Component implements OnInit {
  rider: Rider;

  constructor(
    private _speedwayService: SpeedwayService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute){}

ngOnInit() {
  this.loadZaw();  
}

loadZaw() {
  const id = +this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
  this._speedwayService.getRider(id).subscribe((rider) => {
    this.rider = rider;
})}}
```

**subpage.html**

```
<gs-header>
  <p logo><img src="assets/logo PGEE.jpg" /></p>
  <p levels>HISTORIA MECZÓW - {{ rider.id }}</p>

</gs-header>
```

**data structure (server.js)**

```
// 20210312220521
// http://node.gurustats.usermd.net:60519/pgee2020

{
  "status": 200,
  "message": null,
  "data": [
    {
      "_id": "604a882ed87fdb0482536fc9",
      "MSC": 3,
      "ZAWODNIK": "Bartosz Zmarzlik",
      "KLUB": "Gorzów",
      "SREDNIA": 2.43,
      "id": 103
...
```

[routerlink] & path: "pgee20/:id" are also coded

Comment: Try using `paramMap` instead `this.route.paramMap.get('id')`. According to Angular `params` will be deprecated. https://angular.io/guide/deprecations#activatedroute-params-and-queryparams-properties Maybe it already has?

Comment: I tried, but I got the message: `Property 'get' does not exist on type Observable<ParamMap>`

Comment: Ah sorry, was going based off my head, probably need to add `snapshot` so like `this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');`

Comment: @penleychan The `params` in `this.route.snapshot.params['id']` is the `params` property of `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` class. The linked documentation is about `params` property of `ActivatedRoute` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`http://node.gurustats.usermd.net:60519/pgee2020/[id-of-some-rider]` is not giving you the data of a single rider. That is why the `rider` variable in your component remains `undefined`.

`http://node.gurustats.usermd.net:60519/pgee2020` gives you data in the following shape -

```json
{"status":200,"message":null,"data":[{rider1-data}, {rider1-data}, ...]}
```

and you can get the data of a specific rider by applying `filter` on the `data` array. Also, the response you receive is not really of `Rider` type. Therefore, you need to change the return type of your service method to `Observable<any>`.

Change your service method to -

```js
getRider(id) : Observable<any> {
    return this._http
        .get<any>("http://node.gurustats.usermd.net:60519/pgee2020")
        .map(result => result.data.filter(p=> p.id == id)[0]);
}
```

or, to -

```js
getRider(id) : Observable<any> {
    return this._http
        .get<any>("http://node.gurustats.usermd.net:60519/pgee2020")
        .pipe(
            map(result => result.data.filter(p=> p.id == id)[0])
      );
}
```

depending on your `rxjs` version.

Also, in your HTML, use `*ngIf` to check if `rider` has a value before accessing its properties -

```html
<gs-header>
    <p logo><img src="assets/logo PGEE.jpg" /></p>
    <div *ngIf="rider">
        <p levels>HISTORIA MECZÓW - {{ rider.id }}</p>
    </div>
</gs-header>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I understand the source of the issue. However, I tried both of the proposed solutions and I received the error each time.

The first one:
`Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Response'.`
The second one:
`Cannot find name 'map'. Did you mean 'Map'?`

Comment: I imported {map} from rxjs/operators and the second output has changed. I have two problems now.
`Argument expression expected.`
`Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Response'.`
rxjs version is 5.5.6

Comment: @Rafineria Change `Observable<Rider>` to `Observable<any>` because the response you receive is really not a `Rider` type. I'll update it in the answer.

Comment: Thank you for quick response. Unfortunately, errors remain the same.

Comment: @Rafineria What is your Angular version?

Comment: 5.2.5, CLI 6.0.8

Comment: @Rafineria Please check the updated answer. Notice the `[0]` in the `map()` method and the `*ngIf` in the HTML.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229858/discussion-between-rafineria-and-atiyar).

Comment: Thank you @atiyar, it worked after upgrading my Angular to the newest version!

Comment: @Rafineria Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments above, `params` will be deprecated. So recommend changing the flow to this equivalent code which combined with other answers may solve your problem.

```js
loadZaw() {
    this.route.paramMap.pipe(
        switchMap(routeParaMap => { 
            const id = +routeParaMap.get('id');
            return this._speedwayService.getRider(id);
        }),
        take(1)
    ).subscribe((rider) => {
        this.rider = rider;
    });
}
```

Comment: The `params` that OP is using is the property of `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` class, and it has not been a subject of deprecation.

Comment: You're right atiyar,there's no deprecation in the OP's code, my mistake. Though I don't see anything changed in your proposed edit.